# get-infected method for netlogo simulation not functioning

Tags: netlogo

The following code is a simple simulation for a virus spreading. It isn't working and I can't find out why. `ziek` becomes true when an agent mutates (which is in a different method, but is known to be working). The agent also becomes lime. However my agents only mutate and won't get infected. What am I doing wrong?

```
to get-infected
  ask other turtles [
  if color = gray and turtles-here = ziek
    [set color lime 
      set ziek true]]

end
```

Comment: For those not speaking Dutch: _ziek_ is _sick_.

Answer (score 2):

So `turtles-here` reports an agent set of turtles on the caller's patch (the caller can be another turtle or a patch), [per the NetLogo dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here).  As such comparing `turtles-here = ziek` doesn't make a lot of sense if `ziek` is `true` or `false`, as those values will never be the same (`=`) an agent set of turtles.

To check if any member of the `turtles-here` agent set is sick, you'd want to use [`any?`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any) along with the [`with`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with) primitives.  I think you want something like this:

```
to get-infected
  ask other turtles [
    if color = gray and any? turtles-here with [ziek] [
      set color lime 
      set ziek true
    ]
  ]
end
```

But you could also flip this around - instead of having turtles infect themselves when they see other sick turtles, you can have sick turtles do the infecting.  To me this setup makes more sense.

```
to go
  ; ... other go code to do turtle actions goes here
  ask turtles with [ziek] [
    infect-others
  ]
  ; ... more code here
end

to infect-others
  ask other turtles-here with [not ziek] [
    set color lime 
    set ziek true
  ]
end
```